# Change AppResources in design time

Tags: c#, xaml, localization, windows-phone-8

I am trying to change the display language in design time in windows phone. Basically, I have two AppResources files each populated with localized strings. In my text boxes I have bound it like this:
    TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Title, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"

What I want is a way to change the design time language so I can see the content of the textblock in any of the two languages. I have tried manipulating [assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en-US")] and it worked first but it is no longer working for some reason.

Any idea how can I switch languages (resource files) in design time in windows phone 8?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637522%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) is information about globalization your application and the samples.